# restTemplate Error 403

Tags: java, android, rest, csrf-protection

I'm trying to implemente a request method, but I can't figure out how to sent the X-XSRF-TOKEN to my webservice.

In the webservice, the token is configured to be X-XSRF-TOKEN

```
<beans:bean id="csrfTokenRepository"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
    <beans:property name="headerName" value="X-XSRF-TOKEN" />
</beans:bean>
```

I have it in my android App

```
public class WSConfig {
private static String urlBase = "http://192.168.25.226:8080/webapi/";
private static HttpHeaders httpHeaders;
private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
private static HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity(getXSRF());
private static ResponseEntity<String> response;

public static HttpHeaders getXSRF() {
    try {
    HttpEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(urlBase, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    List<String> cookieHeader = responseEntity.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    if (cookieHeader != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookieHeader) {
            String[] tokens = TextUtils.split(cookie, "=");
            if (tokens[0].equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
                String[] tokenValue = TextUtils.split(tokens[1],";");
                httpHeaders.add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", tokenValue[0]);
            }
            if (tokens[0].equals("JSESSIONID")) {
                String[] tokenValue = TextUtils.split(tokens[1],";");
                httpHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSSESSIONID="+tokenValue[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    } finally {
        return httpHeaders;
    }
}

public static HttpEntity<String> makeRequest(String uri, HttpMethod method) {
    try {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new DefaultResponseErrorHandler(){
            protected boolean hasError(HttpStatus statusCode) {
                return false;
            }});

        System.out.println(httpEntity.getHeaders());
        response = restTemplate.exchange(urlBase + "registrar", HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class);
        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

In my LogCat, I got these results from the System.outs

```
System.out.println(httpEntity.getHeaders());
{Accept=[application/json], Cookie=[JSSESSIONID=D0D537D4C38D2D69B01BF4F98B540763], X-XSRF-TOKEN=[8c21c671-bba4-4624-ada1-ff1e9e8f2e22]}

System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], X-Frame-Options=[DENY], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Set-Cookie=[JSESSIONID=7DBA84F6218BC9A8328A97587FC6293A; Path=/webapi/; HttpOnly], Content-Type=[text/html;charset=utf-8], Content-Language=[en], Content-Length=[1073], Date=[Thu, 20 Aug 2015 00:53:46 GMT], X-Android-Sent-Millis=[1440032027763], X-Android-Received-Millis=[1440032027805], X-Android-Response-Source=[NETWORK 403]}
```

And, the error

```
System.out.println(response.getBody());
HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?
```

I can't figure what I have to do, I'm sending the header correctly, but can't make the post.

**UPDATED**

I'm think that this error have relation with JSESSIONID, instead of XSRF-TOKEN, someway after my first GET ( to get the XSRF ) the session is getting expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

As I said, this error is relationed with JSESSIONID.

When I split the JSESSIONID cookie it is losing something that need to make the cookie alive (the path, maybe?)

So, instead of add the cookie like this

```
httpHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSSESSIONID="+tokenValue[0]);
```

I've attached it this way

```
httpHeaders.add("Cookie", cookie);
```

Making it, I make sure that all content be attached to the new header.

The final method.

```
public static HttpHeaders getXSRF() {
    try {
    HttpEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(urlBase, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    List<String> cookieHeader = responseEntity.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
    httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    if (cookieHeader != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookieHeader) {
            String[] tokens = TextUtils.split(cookie, "=");
            if (tokens[0].equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
                String[] tokenValue = TextUtils.split(tokens[1],";");
                httpHeaders.add("X-XSRF-TOKEN", tokenValue[0]);
            }
            if (tokens[0].equals("JSESSIONID"))
                httpHeaders.add("Cookie", cookie);
        }
    }
    } finally {
        return httpHeaders;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you have a typo in some lines. You write `JSSESSIONID` instead of `JSESSIONID` - notice the double s.